# Algorithms for Deducing a Timeline / Chronology

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for leads on algorithms to deduce the timeline/chronology of a series of novels.  I've split the texts into days and created a database of relationships between them, e.g.: X is a month before Y, Y and Z are consecutive, date of Z is known, X is on a Tuesday, etc.  There is uncertainty ('month' really only means roughly 30 days) and also contradictions. I can mark some relationships as more reliable than others to help resolve ambiguity and contradictions.

What kind of algorithms exist to deduce a best-fit chronology from this kind of data, assigning a highest-probability date to each day?  At least time is 1-dimensional but dealing with a complex relationship graph with inconsistencies seems non-trivial.  I have a CS background so I can code something up but some idea about the names of applicable algorithms would be helpful.  I guess what I have is a graph with days as nodes as relationships as edges.

Comment: Basically, I believe you're talking about constraint-based programming, with probabilities thrown in. Something like [this](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~tw/wecai2002.pdf)?

Comment: Thanks; that's provided plenty of leads for me to follow up.  I'd mark this "answered" if only I could find the tick mark to click on.

Comment: That's not much of an answer though, even if it led you in the right direction. Feel free to summarise your findings in your own answer, and check that; I'm sure it will be more detailed than I can do at this point.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple, crude first approximation to your problem would be to store information like "A happened before B" in a directed graph with edges like "A -> B". Test the graph to see whether it is a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG). If it is, the information is consistent in the sense that there is a consistent chronology of what happened before what else. You can get a sample linear chronology by printing a "topological sort" (topsort) of the DAG. If events C and D happened simultaneously or there is no information to say which came before the other, they might appear in the topsort as ABCD or ABDC. You can even get the topsort algorithm to print all possibilities (so both ABCD and ABDC) for further analysis using more detailed information.

If the graph you obtain is not a DAG, you can use an algorithm like Tarjan's algorithm to quickly identify "strongly connected components", which are areas of the graph which contain chronological contradictions in the form of cycles. You could then analyze them more closely to determine which less reliable edges might be removed to resolve contradictions. Another way to identify edges to remove to eliminate cycles is to search for "minimum feedback arc sets". That's NP-hard in general but if your strongly connected components are small the search could be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Constraint programming is what you need.  In propagation-based CP, you alternate between (a) making a decision at the current choice point in the search tree and (b) propagating the consequences of that decision as far as you can.  Notionally you do this by maintaining a domain `D` of possible values for each problem variable `x` such that `D(x)` is the set of values for `x` which have not yet been ruled out along the current search path.  In your problem, you might be able to reduce it to a large set of Boolean variables, `x_ij`, where `x_ij` is true iff event `i` precedes event `j`.  Initially `D(x) = {true, false}` for all variables.  A decision is simply reducing the domain of an undecided variable (for a Boolean variable this means reducing its domain to a single value, true or false, which is the same as an assignment).  If at any point along a search path `D(x)` becomes empty for any `x`, you have reached a dead-end and have to backtrack.

If you're smart, you will try to learn from each failure and also retreat as far back up the search tree as required to avoid redundant search (this is called *backjumping* -- for example, if you identify that the dead-end you reached at level 7 was caused by the choice you made at level 3, there's no point in backtracking just to level 6 because *no solution* exists in this subtree given the choice you made at level 3!).

Now, given you have different degrees of confidence in your data, you actually have an optimisation problem.  That is, you're not just looking for a solution that satisfies all the constraints that *must* be true, but one which also best satisfies the other "soft" constraints according to the degree of trust you have in them.  What you need to do here is decide on an *objective function* assigning a score to a given set of satisfied/violated partial constraints.  You then want to prune your search whenever you find the current search path cannot improve on the best previously found solution.

If you do decide to go for the Boolean approach, you could profitably look into SAT solvers, which tear through these kinds of problems.  But the first place I'd look is at [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/), a CP language which maps on to a whole variety of state of the art constraint solvers.

Best of luck!